# Cordova Android App Build Issue - Duplicate zip entry

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cordova, gradle

My AngularJS based Cordova project facing various Android build issues recently. It was in gradle version of 2.14.1 with build tools of 2.2.3. However, faced issue as "A problem occurred configuring root project ".

I tried removing android platform and adding again with platform version 6.4.0,

Recent error While perform Cordova build android:

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/*******/***/***/platforms/android/build/intermediates/multi-dex/debug/componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [/Users/*******/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-v4-23.4.0.aar/21482513ed63a92f167953e0b46db339/jars/classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.class]))

I tried using multiDexEnabled as true in defaultconfig, but error remains same,

**Project.properties :**

target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib

cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-android-support-gradle-release/stcmobile-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle

cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+

cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:support-v4:+

cordova.system.library.4=com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1

**Build.gradle :**

```
android {
  ......
  defaultConfig {
     multiDexEnabled true
  }
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
  .......
  compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
  }
  ......
  dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: "CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
    compile "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
  }
}
```

I'm not  in a position to migrate the application to latest Angular and hence this build related issues needs to be fixed.

current Versions details,

- Cordova Android : 6.4
- Cordova : 7.1
- Gradle : 4.1
- com.android.tools.build:gradle : 3.0.0
- compileSdkVersion 26
- buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

Answer (score 0):

After multiple trial and check with various compile sdk and build tools versions, the errors got eliminated and still running the project.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.